# How to decrease the webpage width in a Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, column-width

This is my page: http://www.theonewhogetsit.com/shorter-width/

The large width makes it too hard for the readers to read through it.

I want to basically make cut the width of the page in half (**but only for this page**).

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is the kind of question that sometimes takes a bit of a pasting on this site, don't let that make you think it's any less awesome though :)

You want to create a custom template for this page, here's the link to how to go about dong that;

[Wordpress Custom Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates)

You would copy the existing page.php template, rename it as per the instructions above and then change the HTML markup in that template so the div containing `<?php the_content; ?>` was wrapped in a new id or class. Then you'd use CSS to set the width of that id/class to 50%.

That's a rough guide, if you get stuck then come back with specific questions - paste up your code from the template and your CSS and you will get quick answers here.  Good luck.